# How can I know which functions call a certain TypeScript function, I cannot find an instance where it is called

Tags: javascript, typescript, nearprotocol, fireblocks-sdk

I have a TypeScript function called `signMessage` which is called when I send a transaction (a smart contract call).
https://github.com/fireblocks/fireblocks_matic_near_staking_sdk/blob/main/src/NEAR/NEARFireblocksSigner.ts#L44

For example, I'm calling this `stake` function and I can see in the logs that the `signMessage` function is called, but I can't find the line of code inside the `stake` function or any of the functions called inside it.
I need to return the value `txId` from the `stake` function and I don't know where to get the value from?

```js
    async stake(amount: number): Promise<void> {
        await this.runSetupIfNeeded();
        typecheck(amount, typeof 1);
        this.log('Validating stake request.');
        let nearWallet = await this.fbks.getVaultAccountAsset("" + this.vaultAccountId, this.assetId);
        let nearInWallet = nearWallet.available;
        if (Number.parseFloat(nearInWallet) < amount) {
            throw new Error(`Vault account ${this.vaultAccountId} has ${nearInWallet} NEAR, but requested to stake ${amount}.`);
        }

        this.log('Validated.');
        this.log('Note - stake,unstake and withdraw will print data including reciepts for transaction, make sure to save it for future reference.', 'WRN');

        (this.config.signer as NEARFireblocksSigner).setNote(`NEAR Staking - Staking ${amount} NEAR`);

        // @ts-ignore - required because deposit_and_stake is generated at runtime.
        let response = await this.contract.deposit_and_stake({
            args: {},
            amount: parseNearAmount("" + amount)
        });

        this.log(`Staked ${amount} NEAR to ${this.contractName}.`);
    }
```

Tried debugging function calls, but it didn't work. I couldn't find where it is called, although the compiled JavaScript code shows that `signMessage` is called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

You can see logs of `signMessage` and not an actual call to it because it is an abstract function called inside `near-api-js`

`txId` is not returned in the flow you are using. You will have to create your own flow if you want to use it.

### Long version:

`NEARStaker` [has a property named](https://github.com/fireblocks/fireblocks_matic_near_staking_sdk/blob/a69e61221dc1d4922bda781cd60975533120493a/src/NEAR/NEARStaker.ts#L23) `config.signer` of type `NEARFireblocksSigner` which extends `near-api-js`’s `Signer` [class that holds an abstract](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/signers/src/signer.ts#LL26C18-L26C18) `signMessage`. (Remember that for later).

##### Execution flow:

1. `NEARStaker` constructor [creates](https://github.com/fireblocks/fireblocks_matic_near_staking_sdk/blob/a69e61221dc1d4922bda781cd60975533120493a/src/NEAR/NEARStaker.ts#LL47C20-L47C20) a `Contract` (imported from  `near-api-js`), the contract has [several methods generated in runtime](https://github.com/fireblocks/fireblocks_matic_near_staking_sdk/blob/a69e61221dc1d4922bda781cd60975533120493a/src/NEAR/NEARStaker.ts#L52) (aka `changeMethods`), we care about `deposit_and_stake` which is [called inside](https://github.com/fireblocks/fireblocks_matic_near_staking_sdk/blob/a69e61221dc1d4922bda781cd60975533120493a/src/NEAR/NEARStaker.ts#L80) `stake()`
2. The generated functions have the same [implementation](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/accounts/src/contract.ts#L218) inside `near-api-js`. They all [call](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/accounts/src/contract.ts#L221) `Account`’s `functionCall`.
3. `functionCall` [calls](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/accounts/src/account.ts#LL406C33-L406C33) `signAndSendTransaction`.
4. `signAndSendTransaction` [calls](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/accounts/src/account.ts#LL222C40-L222C60) `signTransaction`.
5. `signTransaction` [calls](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/accounts/src/account.ts#L209) another implementation of `signTransaction` from the `transaction` package.
6. `signTransaction` [calls](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/transactions/src/sign.ts#L45) `signTransactionObject`.
7. `signTransactionObject` [calls](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/4141edda69e4f965419ed35642aede202e996abd/packages/transactions/src/sign.ts#L35) `signMessage` which was implemented by us (see our first line).

I hope this helps clear things out :)